# How to build macros in dbt

Tags: mysql, json, macros, dbt, dbt-mysql

```
{% macro json_extract(json, paths) %}
    CASE
        {% for path in paths.split(',') %}
            WHEN JSON_PARSE({{ json }}), {{ path }} IS NOT NULL
                THEN JSON_PARSE({{ json }}),  {{ path }} 
        {% endfor %}
        ELSE NULL
    END
{% endmacro %}
```

I'm trying to build a macros in my dbt to extract multiple path so I could invoke the macros in my model. Everything I've tried is not working.

This is the last macros I built which is not working still.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, try editing this question so we can actually help you. Do take care to include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [to not use pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).